# Prove that $\sum\frac{(\log n)^2}{n^3}$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence

This question is from Serge Lang's textbook, in a chapter that comes before the ratio and integral tests are introduced, so those can't be used. I've already proved that $\sum\frac{\log n}{n^3}$ converges and have an inkling that this result may be useful, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: How did you prove that $\sum \frac{\log n}{n^3}$ converges?

Comment: $\sum\frac{log n}{n^3}$ < $\sum\frac{n}{n^3}$, which converges.

Comment: Okay. So if you could show that $(\log n)^2 \leqslant n$, you'd be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then use $\ln(n)^2 = 4\ln(\sqrt{n})^2 < 4\sqrt{n}^2$.

Comment: How does $(\ln n)^2 = 4\ln(\sqrt n)^2$?

Comment: Use `\ln` in LaTeX. $\ln(n) = 2\ln(\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove $(\log n)^2 <  n$ for large enough $n$ and compare your series to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\forall \varepsilon>0, \,\, \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^3}<\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^3} \le \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^{3-\varepsilon}}+O(1).
$$